# SwiftUI With Firebase Using Xcode 11 GM seed 2 - Swift UI Firestore

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I followed this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_N10q1iR2HQ&t=328s tutorial; however, adjusted for some changes made to Xcode 11 GM seed 2 syntax and terms, because some stuff is obsolete now. Build is successful, but crashes for some reason.

I would appreciate any help and suggestions, tried all trial and error I could think of.

Here is the code below (pasting all of it since GM seed 2 has many command changes):

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import FirebaseFirestore
struct dataset : Identifiable {
var id = ""
var name = ""
var phone = ""
var services = ""
}
class getData : ObservableObject {

var didChange = PassthroughSubject<getData, Never>()

var data = [dataset](){

    didSet{
        didChange.send(self)
    }
}

init(){
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let settings = db.settings
    settings.areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = true
    db.settings = settings
    db.collection("venues").addSnapshotListener {(snap,err) in
        if err != nil{
            print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
            return
        }
        for i in (snap?.documentChanges)!{

            let name = i.document.data()["name"] as! String
            let phone = i.document.data()["phone"] as! String
            let services = i.document.data()["services"] as! String
            let id = i.document.documentID

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.data.append(dataset(id: id, name: name, phone: phone, services:services))
            }
        }
    }
}
}
struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var data1 = getData()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Hello World")
        List(data1.data){ i in
            cellView(name: i.name, phone: i.phone, services: i.services)
        }
    }
}
}
struct cellView : View {
@State var name = ""
@State var phone = ""
@State var services = ""

var body : some View{
    VStack{
        Text(name)
        Text(phone)
        Text(services)
    }
}
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
}
}
```

These are the results

> 2019-09-19 20:30:34.724594+0600 Venue[16661:712640]  - [I-ACS036002] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
>
> 2019-09-19 20:30:34.975422+0600 Venue[16661:712648] 5.12.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.50300000 started
>
> 2019-09-19 20:30:34.975634+0600 Venue[16661:712648] 5.12.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
>   Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x10b8a8610) to 'NSString' (0x10954f978).
>
> 2019-09-19 20:30:35.073897+0600 Venue[16661:711704] Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x10b8a8610) to 'NSString' (0x10954f978).
>   (lldb)

Comment: Given the error message "Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x10b8a8610) to 'NSString'", it seems like you're trying to hard cast a number to a string, which isn't possible. Most likely one of your fields `name`, `phone` or `services` holds a numeric value. If you right-click on the red error indicator you should be able to find what precise line that is.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the first comment, it looks like you have a cast issue between types.

I tried the same example and was able to build and run successfully, but no data was shown on the screen. After some investigation, I re-wrote some parts of the code and was finally able to get results.

Instead of the video's dataset, I used the following structure:

```
  struct Profile : Identifiable {

  var id: Int
  var name: String
  var phoneNumber: String

  init(id: Int, name: String, phoneNumber: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
  }
}
```

And these are the SwiftUI views:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestore

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var data1 = [Profile]()

    var body: some View {

        return VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Penya").font(.largeTitle)
            }
            Divider()
            List(data1) { i in
                cellView(name: i.name, phoneNumber: i.phoneNumber)
            }
        }.onAppear {
            self.getData()
        }
    }


    func getData() {

        var data = [Profile]()

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("patients").addSnapshotListener { (snap, err) in

            if err != nil {
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }

            for doc in (snap?.documentChanges)! {
                let name = doc.document.data()["name"] as! String
                let phoneNumber = doc.document.data()["phoneNumber"] as! String

                print (name)
                print (phoneNumber)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    data.append(Profile(id: 0,
                                        name: name,
                                        phoneNumber: phoneNumber))
                    self.data1 = data
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

struct cellView : View {

    @State var name = ""
    @State var phoneNumber = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Valors:")
            Text(name)
            Text(phoneNumber)
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Whenever a record is changed in Firestore, an update is automatically performed on the simulator screen. There is only one thing I am still working on: the updated values are correctly shown in the console (I included two print()), but I always see the same original value on the simulator screen even I change the record in Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

Works with Sergi's Code but he was missing the following:

```
let id = doc.document.documentID

DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    data.append(Profile(id: id,
                                        name: name,
                                        phoneNumber: phoneNumber))
                    self.data1 = data
```

and change all values for id to be String instead of Int.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [CombineFirebase](https://github.com/rever-ai/CombineFirebase)
with pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'

Then you can use pure combine pattern for Firestore in your project